# How to move file without knowing the username?

Tags: c#, cmd

I'am writing a program in C#. How to move file without knowing a username? Like C:\Users\ and now there is a username, but I don't know the someones username and how to move it?

```
            var proc2 = new ProcessStartInfo();
            proc2.UseShellExecute = true;

            proc2.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";

            proc2.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
            proc2.Verb = "runas";
            proc2.Arguments = "/c move x.bat C:\Users\HERE";       
            proc2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(proc2);
```

Comment: If you have administrator right than scan users folder and than search each folder for that file location. There are 3 step's scan folder - search file - move file

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ But do you know how to scan it?

Answer (score 1):

The closest would be the environment variable `%userprofile%`, which contains the path to the current user's directory: `C:\Users\Somebody`.

Comment: But do you know how to add it into code that I added in description?

Comment: A quick google search would bring you [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

String foldername = @"C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName

Getting user name with the command : Environment.UserName

Comment: But how to add it into code that is in the description? Can you help me with that?